# Orange flakes forming after salt water electrolysis with rusty iron electrodes

Tags: electrolysis

I am using two old iron bars, rusty from the years, into a solution of tap water saturated with NaCl.

After a few minutes at 32.6V and between 1 and 2 Ampere, I get a clear looking yellowish solution, containing HOCl (which I am after) along other products.

Invariably, letting the solution sit for a while, either in the electrolysis vat itself, or after having immediately transferred it to another container (via a spigot I installed above the electrodes in the vat, which lay on the bottom of it, so any leakage from the eletrodes themselves should stay on the bottom and I should extract only the "clean" solution above), I notice many orange flakes floating around, that end up sedimenting at the bottom.
After this happens, the yellowish solution becomes mostly transparent.

These are the flakes that form in the external container, where I transfer the electrolysed solution of tap water, NaCl and a touch of vinegar, I seal the top, and put it away from sunlight:
[image: flakes inside external container, vinegar had been added into the electrolysis vat]

These are the flakes forming in the electrolysis vat, where I left sitting the electrolysed solution of tap water and NaCl (no vinegar added) near the window and with open top (you can see the electrodes submerged to the bottom through a sealed hole on the side)
[image: flakes formed inside electrolysis vat, no vinegar had been added]

The flakes do not appear ferromagnetic, they are impalpable (as soon as I try catching them with tweezers they disperse or just float away). I suspect they are iron oxides, but not sure.

I would like to know if such solution is "safe" to be used in a pressure spray painter or if I risk clogging the nozzle.

Also, I would like to know if investing in graphite electrodes will prevent such by-products.

Comment: It is Fe(OH)3. No idea if it will clog the nozzle. It is even difficult to be filtered out, so perhaps not.

Comment: @Alchimista how comes it flakes up only after a while, when the solution has been sitting in the container? Before that, the liquid is yellowish in colour, but totally clear

Comment: The formation of a precipitate is a reaction like any other, it may take time to complete. You may try to somewhat reverse it by vigorous stirring, perhaps in an old blender.

Comment: @TAR86 thank you for explaining it's a precipitate; my aim would be to completely avoid having that in the solution, so I will need to go with graphite electrodes.